# High voltage multiplier attempt - low voltage output

Tags: ac, high-voltage, rectifier, multiplier, arc

I have built a 15 stage voltage multiplier in hopes of multiplying an input voltage of 2kV to ~70kV.

This voltage multiplier has been constructed with 3kV 1nF ceramic capacitors and diodes rated at 20kV.

For the input voltage, I am using my own self-wound AC flyback transformer which I have recorded an output of ~2200V.

When I connect this to the voltage multiplier, I get very small arcs that are barely noticeable. This leads me to believe that it is somehow reducing the input voltage and I am not sure as to the reason. [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I haven't seen any parts of the system showing corona discharge where the charge might be leaking. Even though the multiplier is insulated in mineral oil, it is not giving any expected high voltage discharge arc.

I am open to any suggestions or concerns as I am lost as to what to try next. Thank you.

Comment: You didn't post a schematic but I would assume it's a Cockcroft–Walton. What frequency are you running it at?

Comment: *suggestion*: use higher capacitance in the lower stages. Then again, a *flyback* voltage *will* diminish with higher capacitance. (You may want to add resistors for controlled discharge.) Oscillograph as many stages as your probe allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have built many Cockroft-Walton voltage multipliers, and this is normal.

The current at the end of the many stages you have is very low, perhaps in the microamps. Plus, you have many low-value capacitors in series. The impedance at the output is quite high.

What you need to do is reduce the number of stages. Larger capacitors will help, but not to the degree that cutting out all but a few stages will.

---

If you are looking for a corona at the end of this as it is now, solder a .005 inch diameter wire to the end of the last stage, and use diagonal wire cutters to make a very sharp point at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I build this voltage tripler several years ago. After 3 stages I could no longer get any increase in voltage. My input was from 120 VAC power line. I ended up with 900 VDC.

I have worked many year with high voltage circuits in CRT televisions.

The most I saw was 42,000 volts. With your build, even if you got to 20,000 volts it would be arcing between the diodes and capacitors. It has to be HIGHLY insulated.

I once used a 12 volt motorcycle ignition coil and a capacitive discharge ignition system. It used a 100 volts DC supply to get an output that sparked several inches. I don't recall the circuit.

[image]

Comment: (Downvoters please leave a comment *why* an answer is *not useful*.)